# Updating Multiple Rows in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to update multiple rows in a PLSQL block.  Is it possible to update several rows with a single UPDATE statement.
For example, could I use the following code:

```
UPDATE ORDERTABLE
SET COST = 400 AND SHIPPING = 8, AND TAX = .06;
```

Is this acceptable?

Comment: With that syntax, no - `set cost=400, shipping=9, tax=0.06` (without the AND clauses) but you'd have to give a little bit more detail about what you're looking to do.

Comment: if you don't use the `where` condition you will update all the rows of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your update is wrong. But it is possible to update more than one row with one statement.

```
UPDATE ordertable SET
cost = 400, shipping = 8, tax = .06;
```

This will update *all* rows in table ordertable.
Add some restrictions to change only some rows.

```
UPDATE ordertable SET
cost = 400, shipping = 8, tax = .06
WHERE cost < 100 OR shipping >9;
```

Most tools report rows updated as output or feedback. You can check which rows are updated prior running the update, by using the restriction in a select statement.

```
SELECT * FROM ordertable
WHERE cost < 100 OR shipping >9;
```

Answer (score 0):

More than one rows cant be updated in a single update statement.
Once the update statement is executed you will get output as

```
n Rows Updated
```

where n -is the no of rows for which the update statement is executed successfully.

Below code update all the rows of the table

```
UPDATE ORDERTABLE
SET COST = 400,
    SHIPPING = 8,
    TAX = .06;
```